# Simple Closed Curve Under Dehn Filling.

Tags: geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Let us consider the figure eight knot($K$) complement in $S^3$. Let $\gamma$ be an essential simple closed loop inside the figure eight knot complements in $S^3$.Now thicken the knot and consider the tube following the knot. That is the torus following the knot $T$, say. The 1st fundamental group boundary of $S^3 \setminus K$ i.e $\pi_1(S^3 \setminus K)$ is
$\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ let us consider the generators $a$ and $b$ let $s$ be the slope on the torus say $s=a^mb^n$ . Let $M$ be a closed 3-manifold manifold attaching a solid torus $D^2 \times S^1$ with respect to the slope $s$.Which is called s-Dehn filling and $M$ is denoted by $M(s)$

1)Does this $\gamma$ simple or not after Dehn filling? If not, are there any conditions on the Dehn filling it will be a simple closed curve in the Dehn-filled manifolds?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The expression " filling the knot flowing torus by Dehn filling" is very unclear: There is a standard notion of Dehn surgery on a knot, is this what you have in mind? One way to describe it is by attaching a solid torus to the knot exterior, $E(K)$, along the boundary torus. Such attachment does not change properties any curves in $E(K)$, of course. Is this what you want to know? Or, do you mean a hyperbolic Dehn surgery and behavior of closed geodesics? All in all, you question is unclear as written and I am voting to close for now.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually, I want to know how to control essential simple closed loops under Dehn Filling mentioned above. More precisely, if I know the 1st fundamental group of knot complements in  $S^3$, then can we get 1st fundamental group of Dehn-filled manifolds?

Comment: That's a very different question from what you wrote. Did you learn van Kampen's theorem?

Comment: Yes, I know Van Kampen's theorem. I read it from the algebraic topology book by Allen Hatcher.

Comment: The result of Dehn filling/surgery is the union of the knot exterior, $E(K)$, and the solid torus, glued along the boundary torus of $E(K)$. Since you know van Kampen's theorem, you will have no trouble computing the fundamental group from this information (it will depend, of course, not only on $\pi_1(E(K))$ but also on the Dehn surgery parameter). However, it has nothing to do with simple loops whatsoever.